# Script getting current git branch without commandline

Tags: bash

I use this little script for merging the current branch into the trunk. Branch name is taken from arguments. How can I take it from `git branch`?

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout $1
nosetests
git checkout master
git merge $1
git push
git checkout $1
```

Comment: Does `git branch | sed -E 's/^\*[[:blank:]]*//' | while IFS= read -r f; do git checkout "$f"; done` work for you?

Comment: First check if thats work for you. Just run and see.

Comment: It spews a lot of nonsense, dont think so.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. What's a "trunk"? It's not part of standard Git vocabulary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the name of the current `HEAD`, I would like to tell you about

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

([Source](//stackoverflow.com/a/1418022/2461638))

Answer (score 2):

Implemented it in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["git", "branch"]).decode("utf8")
current = next(line for line in out.split("\n") if line.startswith("*"))
print(current.strip("*").strip())
```

Comment: I'm relatively sure that the [Python module for Git operations](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/) has a command more similar to my answer (that doesn't require spawning a sub-process and read its output from a pipe).

Comment: `git.Repo().active_branch.name`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output(["git","symbolic-ref", "--short", "HEAD"]).decode("utf8")[0:-1]
'master'
```

shorter version in python.